# Hash in the output of a cell

Tags: matrix

I am just getting started with this and I am trying to diagonalize a matrix symbolically. I have have this code:

```
A = {{0, a, 0}, {a, b, c}, {0, c, d}}
DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[A]]
```

And this is my output:

```
{{Root[a^2 d + (-a^2 - c^2 + b d) #1 + (-b - d) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 0, 
  0}, {0, 
  Root[a^2 d + (-a^2 - c^2 + b d) #1 + (-b - d) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
  0}, {0, 0, 
  Root[a^2 d + (-a^2 - c^2 + b d) #1 + (-b - d) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}}
```

I understand that `#` is some sort of placeholder for functions, but I am not sure why it appears in my output? How can I just get the diagonal matrix in term of its elements? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have [more unknown variables than equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)

```
matA = {{0, a, 0}, {a, b, c}, {0, c, 0}}; (* remove d *)
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[matA];
DiagonalMatrix[eigenvalues];

(*{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2 (b - Sqrt[4 a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]), 0}, {0, 0, 
  1/2 (b + Sqrt[4 a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2])}}*)
```

For more details on `#1` (or `Slot`) have a look here: [explanation of #1 and #2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167789/explanation-of-1-and-2)